# Jupyterlab health check failing for AI Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

The JupyterLab health check is intermittently failing for my AI Notebook. I noticed that Jupyter service still works even when the health check fails, since my queries still get executed successfully, and I'm able to open my notebook by clicking "Open Jupyterlab".

How can I debug why this health check is failing?

[jupyterlab status failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTuvd.png)

Comment: Are you using container based instance?

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature in Jupyter Notebooks, there is a now a health agent which runs inside Notebook and this specific check is to verify Jupyter Service status:

The check is:

```
if [ "$(systemctl show --property ActiveState jupyter | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')" == "active" ]; then echo 1; else echo -1; fi
```

You can use the `gcloud notebooks instance get-health` to get more details.

What is the DLVM version/image you are using and Machine type?

If you are using container based the check is:

```
docker exec -i payload-container ps aux | grep /opt/conda/bin/jupy
ter-lab | grep -v grep >/dev/null 2>&1; test $? -eq 0 && echo 1 || echo -1
```

And make sure: `report-container-health` and `report-system-health` are both True.